# How to integrate multiple framework calls to openURL:(NSURL *)url

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, dropbox-api

This is to try and get both frameworks to load the URL Schemes from my .plist file in my iOS app. Currently the .plist is formatted as such:

```
URL Types (array) > 
Item 0 (dictionary) > 
URL Schemes (array) > 
item 0 (string) - fbfacebookappkey 
item 1 (string) - db-dropboxappkey
```

Is this correct firstly?

Here is my appdelegate code that is failing:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
     //Facebook specific code  
     return [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]];
    //Dropbox specific code
        DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] handleOpenURL:url];
    if (account)
    {
        DBFilesystem *filesystem = [[DBFilesystem alloc] initWithAccount:account];
        [DBFilesystem setSharedFilesystem:filesystem];

        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How does it fail? Also, you seem to be 'return'ing the FBAppCall line, so the rest wouldn't be running.

Comment: My issue is that I don't know how to return both the facebook and the dropbox keys. I'm new to objective-c if you couldn't tell.

Comment: Do you actually need to return the FBAppCall handleOpenURL? I can't offer any insight on that, but I would expect you just need to have that code run. The Dropbox code does just need to run to finish the auth flow. The return itself is actually for application openURL... https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: So you should write your logic to return accordingly, per the docs under Return Value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your app delegate code to the following:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation
{
     //Facebook specific code  
     if( [FBAppCall handleOpenURL:url
                  sourceApplication:sourceApplication
                        withSession:[PFFacebookUtils session]])
          return YES;

    //Dropbox specific code
        DBAccount *account = [[DBAccountManager sharedManager] handleOpenURL:url];
    if (account)
    {
        DBFilesystem *filesystem = [[DBFilesystem alloc] initWithAccount:account];
        [DBFilesystem setSharedFilesystem:filesystem];

        return YES;
    }
    else
        return NO;
}
```

Otherwise only Facebook url will work.

Comment: So simple! Derp. I was thinking of trying a complicated if source application is ____. Thank you for restoring sanity.